# Sites and services design for branches those having same subnet

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have 2012 domain and about 50 of workstation and servers together in it at branch (A) and now I get another branch (B) with about another 75 workstations and servers (domain 2012). I need to consolidate them in one bigger network. I am willing to implement sites and services. But thing is that right now both branches has networks 192.168.0.0/24.

I have never done this before on my own and I did read the instructions but it got me confused what be the right way to get things done.

I am thinking to switch one of branches adresses to 192.168.1.0/24 network. I am not quite sure what to do the best about all it. How is the best practice designs would work on that kind of cases?

Comment: Setting AD Sites and Services aside you'll need to renumber one of the networks if you intend to have arbitrary IP communication between hosts in both locations. I'd also do yourself a favor, from a VPN perspective, and not use 192.168.1.0/24 in either location. That network is used by a _lot_ of home NAT routers. I'd pick something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same subnet stretching both sites, you can't effectively use AD Sites & Services. It requires different subnets per site. As you've said - switching one site to `192.168.1.0/24` (or any other unsused subnet for that matter) and defining both subnets and assigning one to each site is the basics of what you need to do.

If you ever grow to more than two sites, you'll need to consider site links, but that doesn't matter in a 2 site topology.